# CSS Specificity - external style sheet vs internal style sheet using just classes

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have two CSS classes on one HTML element: `.c-headline-1` and `.c-hero__headline`. In my external style sheet, I'm using `.c-headline-1` and in an internal style sheet (`<style type="text/css">`) I'm using `.hero__headline`, but for some reason the `.c-headline-1` property values are overwriting some of `.hero__headline`'s property values. For example, if both have a font size declaration,  `.c-headline-1` is behaving as if it has higher specificity since it's overwriting `.c-hero__headline`'s font size.

I thought internal style sheets had higher specificity than external style sheets or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All stylesheets are treated the same, what's important is the order in which the styles are declared. For visualization, imagine it this way: The browser takes all CSS files and combines it in one big css file (in the order that they appear in the source code). Then it should be clear why a style is getting overridden if you know how specifications in CSS work.

Comment: Thanks @cloned here's MDN reference confirming your answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the order is important? Isn't it first a priority order where number one is the most significant and its styling will be applied first.

1. Inline styling
2. Internal stylesheets (style withing head element)
3. External stylesheets (link href="style.css" etc.)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're wrong. Internal and external stylesheets have equal priority. Thanks to MDN among others, the notion that they had different priorities became a widely held misunderstanding.

Comment: @Alohci is correct: internal and external stylesheets have equal priority. Here's the MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style